# Spark Streaming: Write dataframe to ElasticSearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I using the following code to write a stream to elasticsearch from python (pyspark) application.

```
#Streaming code
query = df.writeStream \
.outputMode("append") \
.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/") \
.option("es.resource", "logs/raw") \
.option("es.nodes", "localhost") \
.start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

If I write the results to the console it works fine, also, if I write to ES - not in streaming mode, it works ok. This is the code I used to write to ES:

```
#Not streaming
df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
.mode('append') \
.option("es.resource", "log/raw") \
.option("es.nodes", "localhost").save("log/raw")
```

The thing is, I can't debug it, the code is running, but nothing is written to ES (in streaming mode).

Thanks,

Comment: What's the question then? What does not work?

Answer (score 3):

Eventually did work out for me, the problem was technical (needed vpn)

```
query = df.writeStream \
.outputMode("append") \
.queryName("writing_to_es") \
.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/") \
.option("es.resource", "index/type") \
.option("es.nodes", "localhost") \
.start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
val stream = df
      .writeStream
      .option("checkpointLocation", checkPointDir)
      .format("es")
      .start("realtime/data")
```

SBT Dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" %% "elasticsearch-spark-20" % "6.2.4"
```